# Operators in While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, operators

I saw this while loop, but the '!' operator confuses me, which is outside the parentesis.
Is there anyone who can explain to me exactly what thhe line below means?

```
while (!(animal >= legs)) {
```

**My explanation:**

I know, '>=' that means that animal is greater than or equal to legs, but '!' confuses me, it means that they are not **equal to each other**, right? But '>=' means greater than or **equal to each other**. So to the conclusion, does the line mean that animal is just greater than legs?

Comment: `!` just means "not". So `!(animal >= legs)` means "animal is **not** greater than or equal to legs".

Comment: logically same as while (animal < legs)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks alot :-)

Comment: @Gee2113 it can be, but it's not if `animal` or `legs` are floating-point numbers (e.g. if one or both operand is NaN).

Comment: @Andy Turner - yes you are correct, fair point. I was assuming int